# ipkg/opkg how to install certain package by specified version?

Tags: nas, opkg

When I was going to install some package on my NAS via ipkg I found there are more than one versions such as:

```
root@Nas:/opt/etc/init.d# ipkg list | grep openssl
openssl - 0.9.8v-2 - Openssl provides the ssl implementation in libraries libcrypto and libssl, and is needed by many other applications and librari
openssl - 0.9.7m-6 - Openssl provides the ssl implementation in libraries libcrypto and libssl, and is needed by many other applications and librari
```

Due some dependency issue I need the version 0.9.7. However, if I just type `ipkg install openssl` it will always install the later, aka the 0.9.8, one.

Does anybody know how to specify the version to install?

Answer (score 3):

This functionality was introduced in opkg [0.3.2](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/opkg/snapshot/opkg-0.3.2.zip), taken from the [commit](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/opkg/commit/?id=9da784d5508157cb327d53eb9abcf54e9926a5a5) message:

> If several versions of a package are available in a repo, opkg defaults
>   to the latest one. To force opkg to use a different version, the syntax
>   = is used. For example, in a repo that has
>   version 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0 of 'a', the following command will install
>   version 1.0:
>
> opkg install a=1.0
>
> The syntax is the same used by apt-get.

[Here's](https://code.google.com/archive/p/opkg/issues/76) the issue and 0.3.2's [release notes](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opkg-devel/XoN-b1lmIlE)